# Apply for ESTA while having an unexpired B1/B2 visa in another citizenship passport (expired)

Tags: visas, usa, esta, b1-b2-visas, dual-nationality

I have 2 nationalities and 2 passports.

- Passport 1 -> expired (with no possibility of renewing because of country political reasons) -> Valid B1/B2 visa until 2026
- Passport 2 -> eligible for an ESTA

I cannot use my B1/B2 visa because the passport is expired. I want to apply for an ESTA but I am worried it will be refused when they see I have a valid visa. Will it?

Please do not suggest renewing the passport with the visa because it is just not possible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141561/discussion-on-question-by-katrina-apply-for-esta-while-having-an-unexpired-b1-b2).

Comment: Wondering about the same but the passport with B1/B2 is not expired. So basically ESTA vs B1/B2.